# JSON object has values, but they're empty

Tags: json, discord.js

This is JSON 101 but I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.
This is for a discord.js bot, where a command has client passed to it. The client exists and provides all of the data that I would expect to see. The problem is that I then do not have access to the guilds or channel ids

Code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'command',
  execute(client) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(client))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(client.guilds))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(client.channels))
  }
}
```

My response (reduced for "easier" reading):

```
{
  "guilds": [
    "00101010101010101"
  ],
  "channels": [
    "101010101010101010",
    "101010011010101010"
  ]
}
{}
{}
```

Comment: Is this an instance of `Client`? `Client.guilds` and `Client.channels` are both managers, not arrays. I'm just curious even though it doesn't really have anything to do with the answers

Comment: To access the collection of <id, obj> use the `cache` property for both: `Client.guilds.cache` and `Client.channels.cache`

Comment: Additionally, running `JSON.stringify()` on a `Map` (`Collection extends Map`) will give `{}` no matter how many items are in the `Map`